# Write value to a textbox in Userform - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a value dynamically in Textbox which is placed on a Userform. This is my code, and I am getting an error in the last line. It says object required.

```
Sub Userform1_Display()

TotalSelected = 0

With Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox

    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) = True Then
          Count = 1
          TotalSelected = TotalSelected + Count
        End If
    Next i

End With

'Useform'
Questionaire.Show

'TextBox placed in Userform'
N_Ent_TextBox.Value = TotalSelected


End Sub
```

Kindly share your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code isn't actually inside the userform's class module - so you need to fully qualify the object:

```
Questionaire.N_Ent_TextBox.Value = TotalSelected
```

Comment: No worries, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Will Accept it. It says I have to wait for 6 minutes to accept it :)

Answer (score -1):

N_Ent_TextBox.Text = TotalSelected
try to use this

Comment: No, It still says object required !